# Why does DigitalOcean k8s node capacity shows subtracted value from node pool config?

Tags: kubernetes, resources, digital-ocean

I'm running a 4vCPU 8GB Node Pool, but all of my nodes report this for Capacity:

```
Capacity:
  cpu:                4
  ephemeral-storage:  165103360Ki
  hugepages-2Mi:      0
  memory:             8172516Ki
  pods:               110
```

I'd expect it to show `8388608Ki` (the equivalent of `8192Mi`/`8Gi`).

How come?

Answer (score 0):

Memory can be reserved for both system services (`system-reserved`) and the Kubelet itself (`kube-reserved`). https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/reserve-compute-resources/ has details but DO is probably setting it up for you.